# Height:100% does not work to resize my div

Tags: html, css, shopify

This is a result of my previous question. I know that i need to set a specific percentage for the image in the centre of my page so that when the screen size increases/decreases, the image stays in proportion to this. Essentially, i need the image in the centre of my website to be the size of the 'panel', and fit entirely in that panel so that there is no scroll.

The site can be found here:

https://mimi-fasi.myshopify.com/

I'm sure this is fairly basic stuff, but i cannot get it to work.

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="flexslider type-header scaled-text-base">
  <ul class="slides">
   <li class="slide slide-1 flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2;">
  <a href="/collections/all">
  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0727/2709/t/2/assets/slide_1.jpg?155" alt="Slide 1" draggable="false">

  <div class="overlay-text posx-left posy-bottom"> 
    <div class="inner">

      <h1 class="text-1"><span class="scaled-text" style="font-size: 5.83333333333333%;">Welcome to</span></h1>
      <h2 class="text-2"><span class="scaled-text" style="font-size: 5.83333333333333%;">Masonry for Shopify</span></h2>

    </div>
  </div>

  </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, #content is effectively going to contain all of the products (on the catalog screen), which needs to be scrollable, hence why #content cannot be fixed.

CSS:

```
#content {
max-width: 940px;
transition: padding 250ms;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
left: 260px;
top: 100px;
}

.flexslider {
position: relative;
zoom: 1;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.flexslider .slides {
overflow: hidden;
zoom: 1;
margin: 0;
}
.slides, .flex-control-nav, .flex-direction-nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
```

Just to clarify, the image resizes when the screen size changes, which is exactly what i want. However, i want to set a max height for the div depending on the size of the screen, so that the slider/image fills the panel.

**One last thing, this code:**

```
.flexslider .slides img {
max-width: 100%;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

Works fine for width, so if i change the max width/the width down, it all changes and work perfect. I am only attempting to do the same thing with the height, however, this does not work.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the `max-height` to the parent element i.e. `.flexslider` see that helps?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your CSS:

```
html, body {
 height: 100%
}
```

You have to set the height of each container of the `<div>` as well.

Comment: If i add this code, my navigation bar disappears for some reason.